# Problema ao deletar imagem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arquivo

Tenho uma imagem que é o avatar do meu usuário, daí preciso deletar e tenho os seguintes trechos de código:

**Action que é utilizada no import do arquivo**

```
public void MinhaActionParaImport()
{
    var arquivo = Request.Files[0];
    var caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg");
    arquivo.SaveAs(caminho);
}
```

**Método utilizado para remover a imagem**

```
public void DeletarImagem()
{
    var imagem = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagem))
        System.IO.File.Delete(imagem);
}
```

**Método utilizado para exibir a imagem**

```
public ActionResult ExibirImagem()
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg"));
    ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().First(c => c.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);
    return File(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg"), codec.MimeType);
}
```

**View**

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ExibirImagem")"/>
```

Ao tentar fazer isso, recebo o seguinte erro:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

O que posso fazer pra forçar a exclusão dessa imagem?

Comment: Normalmente é o `.vshost` que segura os ponteiros de arquivo. Como você fez para fazer o upload do arquivo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, usei o `SaveAs()` do `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Comment: Pode colocar o código completo na pergunta, por favor?

Comment: Fiz as alterações.

Comment: A mensagem indica que este arquivo está aberto em algum outro aplicativo. Pode ser na sua aplicação ASP.NET MVC ou fora dela. Seu código está ok.

Comment: Provavelmente é na minha aplicação MVC. Se ela estiver sendo exibida na página durante a exclusão, a operação não pode ser feita? Existe alguma forma de forçar isso?

Comment: Você abre a imagem antes, então? Se sim, pode novamente editar sua pergunta e colocar o código?

Comment: Adicione todo o código relevante à manipulação da imagem.

Comment: Adicionei o código e vi o problema, eu tava abrindo um `Image` sem o `using`. Se quiserem bolar uma resposta legal, fiquem a vontade. Se não quiserem, faço depois.

Comment: @FilipeOliveira Não precisa. Sua resposta está ótima. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorreu por estar abrindo a imagem sem fechar.

No trecho de código:

```
public ActionResult ExibirImagem() 
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg"));
    ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().First(c = > c.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);
    return File(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg"), codec.MimeType);
}
```

Deveria estar assim:

```
public ActionResult ExibirImagem() 
{
    string mimeType;
    using(Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg"))) 
    {
        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().First(c = > c.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);
        mimeType = codec.MimeType;
    }
    return File(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Minha/Pasta/"), "foto.jpg"), mimeType);
}
```